# Android Service Notication for Stopwatch Timer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to update the timer in the notification in **HH:MM:SS** format. I have a Service class where the timer is incremented. I can only display the seconds in the notification. I have some trouble with displaying the time in the mentioned format.

This is MyService.java class

```
package com.alfen.timerservice;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "NotificationChannelID";

    static int sec = 0;
    Timer timer;

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());
        startService(restartServiceIntent);
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {

        sec = intent.getIntExtra("sec", 0);
        timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("Timer");
                sec++;
                
                String ty = setTime(sec);  //Also can I do this? I think this is throwing some exception
                try{NotificationUpdate(sec,ty);}catch(Exception e){}

                intent.putExtra("sec", sec);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }, 0, 1000);


//        toast("MyService is running");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        timer.cancel();
        toast("Timer Stopped");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("flag", false);
    }


 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void NotificationUpdate(Integer sec, String t) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Timer")
                .setContentText(sec.toString()) //this is working fine
         //     .setContentText(t)  
                          //When I try to do this the app crashes when the service is started 
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1,notification);

        NotificationChannel nc = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,"Timer Notification"
                ,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        NotificationManager nm = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);

        nm.notify(1,notification);
    }

    private String setTime(int sec) {

        int hours = sec / 3600;
        int mins = (sec%3600) /60;
        int secs = sec % 60;

        String t = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d:%02d",hours,mins,secs);

        toast(t);
        return t;
    }

    public void toast(String s){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to call the setTime() function inside onStartCommand the app keeps crashing

If I change the function like this (without passing the String argument) its working.

```
 public void NotificationUpdate(Integer sec) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Timer")
                .setContentText(sec.toString())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
```

How do I solve this? Also how to do the same using a custom Notification layout using **RemoteViews**?

Comment: Why there are two `.setContentText()`? Could you provide your crash logcat?

Comment: Its a typo. I've commented one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The simple trick is that update your notification data and call notification with different notification id when time is changed. Hope it will work.

Comment: Do I do that using a different function? Sorry if that's so obvious. I'm new to Services.

Comment: Just call the notification builder and notify every time when time changes with different notification id.

Comment: I tried that and I got more than one notification at certain times. I still don't know how to pass a string to the builder function. whenever I try to do that, the app is either crashing or no notification is sent. Can you help with that?

Comment: Call the method which returns the formatted time from notification builder method. And set formatted output to notification content.